# Parse Server Unsupported URL

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, parse-platform

I am currently using Parse server on Heroku which I got deployed using this link over here:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example#with-the-heroku-button

You simply click on the button, create an `application ID, client key, and server URL` which you use to connect to the Parse server from your iOS code.

Now in my app whenever I start it up I keep getting this error:

```
[Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 2.252750 seconds.
[Error]: unsupported URL (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)
```

Even when I try to make a request to grab the data in a PFFile in the code below I get the same error as above:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FollowersTableViewCell

        cell.userNameLabel.text = followUsernameArray[indexPath.row]
        let file = avaArray[indexPath.row]
        file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if let data = data {
                    //ERROR HERE. UNSUPPORTED URL!!??
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    cell.avaImageView.image = image
                }
            }else if error != nil {
                print("FROM FOLLOWERS TABLE VC cellForRowAtIndexPath: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

I already went to `Plist.info` and set the `App Transport Security Settings` to `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to `YES`. That didn't fix the problem either. Does anyone have any input on this? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the code you are using to initialize the Parse SDK? You have to change to something like this: Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
      .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
      .build()
    );

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that the image name in the server had an space "long name.png", which I guess is a invalid character for them, changed it to longName.png and worked without any error. I was using back4app as my Parse Server.

Comment: Upgrade your Parse Server to the latest version (Sign in Back4app -> click in your app features -> Parse Version). This issue is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the Parse iOS SDK has problems connecting to the Parse Server.

You can check from both sides and determine where it faults.

**Parse SDK:**

Check your connection URL in

```
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(ParseClientConfiguration {
    config in
    config.applicationId = <...>
    config.clientKey = <...>
    config.server = <...> // Check this URL
})
```

The URL should look something like this for Heroku:

```
https://<your-heroku-app-name>.herokuapp.com/parse
```

**Parse Server:**

Go to your Heroku dashboard and open the "Logs" page to see if:

- Your Parse Server is up and running without errors, you may want to restart the server while looking at the Log output to see the initialization messages.
- Whats happens when the SDK tries to connect to Parse Server.

To get more info in the logs in the Heroku dashboard go to *Settings > Config Vars* and set the environment variable `VERBOSE` with value `1`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I changed the URL to include the `https` I only had `http` but that didn't seem to do the trick. I also went to the Heroku dashboard but didn't see a Logs page. Do I have to change something in the `parse server` code that is deployed to Heroku?

Comment: Search for the Logs page on Heroku, it is a standard feature on Heroku and without it you won't know what's going on on the server side. Then try entering the URL of parse server in a web browser, what do you see in the browser, what do you see in the parse server logs on Heroku?

Comment: When I enter the ParseServer URL in my browser with this format: `https://<your-heroku-app-name>.herokuapp.com/parse` I see 1{"error":"unauthorized"}`. Let me check out the logs really quick.

Comment: So I looked at the logs after running my app and it doesn't seem like there were any error. But I still keep getting these errors: `2016-09-20 14:07:02.742 APP[2386:176276] [Error]: unsupported URL (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)`
`2016-09-20 14:07:02.743 APP[2386:176276] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 12.655467 seconds.`

Comment: @1290 What are you seeing in the server logs when you try to make the request? Btw the {"error":"unauthorized"} is expected and normal.

Comment: @1290 Just a guess but the "unsupported URL" could also be is the URL of your database that your parse server can't access. What did you set for parameter `databaseURI` in your parse server? You could also make a query directly in cloud code to exclude the possibility that there is a connection problem between the iOS SDK and your parse server.

Comment: Hello Manuel. Where do I check the code where I set `databaseURI` in my parse server. Is there some `index.js` file?

Comment: @1290 Yes, there is, it's on heroku. If you did a 1-Click-Deploy with the Heroku button then it has been generated for you. Connect to your git repository on Heroku where your index.js lies. Also, check the settings page of your Heroku app, maybe there is an environment variable set for the database URI. An environment variable would override the URI in the index.js file.

Comment: Ok so I have a MONGODB_URI config variable with the value in the format of `mongodb://heroku_SOME_LETTERS:MORE_VALUES@ds_SOME_NUMBERS.ml‌​ab.com:PORT_NUMBER/h‌​eroku_SOME_RANDOM_LE‌​TTERS` Is  this the database URI parameter that you were referring to?

Comment: Yes. The URI looks fine. Heroku automatically created a free database with mlab for you. You can try to create a new database at mlab by signing up for a free account yourself. Then change the URI to your own. With that you gain control over your database end and can also analyze from there. Did you try executing a query in cloud code?

Comment: To execute the query in the cloud code would that mean to go to index.js and do something like this: https://parse.com/questions/cloud-code-query-not-working. I am not quite sure by what you mean when you say execute the query in the cloud code. Also if I have to go to `index.js` then do I have to deploy it to git using this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git?

Comment: @1290 Yes, you would have to deploy cloud code to Heroku, for example via git. The cloud code is in /cloud/main.js which you will see when you do your first pull from the Heroku git. If that all sounds unfamiliar to you I suggest you look for a tutorial on how to deploy parse-server-example to Heroku manually, without the 1-Click-deploy button. It will make you familiar with some basics that are good to know if you want to create and maintain a Parse app and you will learn some interesting stuff :)

Comment: Yes I think I will end up doing that actually. Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.